# Pandas -- search column for a string and classify them in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have let's say following DF:

---

```
|Tweet|

|bla bla bad| 

|bla bla good|
```

---

From that I want to create something like:

---

```
|Tweet|           |Sentiment|

|bla bla bad|     |negative|

|bla bla good|    |positive|
```

---

I can search for string in a column with `df[df['Tweet'].str.contains("bad|sad", na=False)]` but how can I then create new column classifying them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['sentiment'] = np.where(df['Tweet'].str.contains('bad|sad'), 'negative', 'positive')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          Tweet sentiment
0   bla bla bad  negative
1  bla bla good  positive
```